# npm install fails with code ELIFECYCLE. Failed at the node-expat@2.3.18 install script

Tags: node.js

He.

I received This error when I am trying to run "npm install" on my project.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.18 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.18 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have tried many things. Reinstall NodeJS, reinstall npm, do 'npm install --global - windows-build-tools production'
But nothing seems to work

Comment: things to try, delete `package-lock.json`, `node_module`, and remove `node-expat` from `package.json`, then do npm i, after that try install `node-expat` separately using `npm i --save node-expat` and see if that goes away.

Comment: Install Visual Studio C++ 2012 and run npm with the --msvs_version=2012 flag.

Comment: https://github.com/astro/node-expat